# Gensim and unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode, gensim

I have this:

```
texts = ['human', 'machine', 'interface']
```

When I do this with Gensim:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
```

It leads to unicode `u'`'s being added... How can I suppress this?

Comment: Why? There is no need to supress it. Python marks unicode strings with prefix `u`.

Comment: I don't know why it bothers you, but you can map `str` onto your results (assuming Python 2).

Comment: It bothers me because it is part of a script for topic modelling and I get different results than the tutorial I am following, and assuming it is due to some encoding issue making spaces or `u'`s counting as tokens.

Comment: @textnet there is no reason to worry about it. I think different results are due to another reason.

Comment: @textnet that almost certainly isn't the reason you are getting different results. For sure, the `u`s won't be counted as tokens... There **are no u's**

Answer (score 0):

If you think the error is because of unicode, you can try this.

```
u'whateveryourwtring'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
u'aあä'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```